# My master’s thesis’ results will be published without my consent. What should I do?

Tags: publications, plagiarism

Last year I finished my master’s. I spent the whole year working on experiments for my master's thesis. Part of the results I obtained were published in my master’s thesis, which was submited via an online tool to my university; so there is proof that that work is mine, I guess.

Then I was offered to stay in that research group and do a PhD, but I refused. They went as far as to threaten me with publishing my data without crediting me. I still refused.

Now it has come to my attention that my data has been used to write a paper that will soon be sent for publishing. Besides that threat from months ago, no one has asked for my consent or permission to use my data, and I don’t even know if my name will be among the authors. Even if it does, I won’t be first author, because they will be assigning that to the person who wrote it.
(I’m not sure how much they have written themselves, as I already had written nearly everything myself for when I had to hand it in for it to be graded for my master.)

My questions are: if I am actually asked for permission before they send it to a journal for publishing and they say they will include my name but not as first author, is it worth accepting or should I refuse? In the case they don’t ask me for permission, what should I do? Mail the journal once the paper is published along with my master's thesis and the raw data (all I have are excel files) to prove the data is stolen?

---

I understand the confusion in some answers, as my case is very chaotic.
As far as I'm concerned, my thesis is not available to the public. Only my advisor and the director of the master have access to it (maybe more people at the university, but it's definitely not available to the public). 
I also know from a case of a person who did his master's thesis in this same research group and then left, and he was asked for permission before the paper using his data was written. He was also credited as an author. 
Sadly, the fact that the boss holds a grudge against me for not wanting to stay and her having a favorite (the one who will be credited as first author) also plays a major role in this.
In my field, being a first (or last) author means you are who worked the most in that paper. It's usually the boss/advisor and the person who obtained most of the data by working in the lab.

Comment: Could you clarify if your data are being used for another paper (as question text), or is part of your master thesis being published (as title)?

Comment: Is your thesis available to the general academic public? Or is it only available to academics at your old university?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but let's say I obtained results A, B and C. Due to the thesis having a max length, only A and B were included in it. Now they want to publish the results in a journal, and C has also been included. I'm not sure if they just took my thesis and expanded it or have rewritten the whole thing using my thesis as a basis (pretty sure it's the latter). I think my thesis is only available for people at my university.

Comment: Do you know what you signed when you first signed up for the Masters course?  There may have been a bunch of legalese in that regarding ownership and rights on the completed thesis.

Comment: Needs further information.  What country are you in?  In the US, at least in my experience, a thesis is automatically "published" (even if not as a journal article) once it is accepted.  Were you funded to do your research?  Then as I understand US law, the results belong to your employer.

Comment: If they use content from your thesis without citing you it's basically plagiarism. If it is your research group/adviser it is borderline as they might already have rights on it. It would not be good research ethic anyway. After all, citing you is not a problem. If they "only" use your gathered data, which they may have rights on, it is IMHO not yet plagiarism but you should be at least cited or acknowledged. Usually being on the authors list is common practice and not doing that might be very rude depending on the amount of your input on the paper.

Comment: What you can do, if you find out to which journal they sent to, is to contact this journal and tell them that this paper contains your data for which you are not credited. I know of one case where the journal pulled the already accepted paper after such a complaint in a very similar case (adviser published paper on PhD graduates data without crediting her at all). You could also complain to the science board of your university, which might be a good first step before contacting the journal. Note that both will NOT make you any new friends on your previous university!

Comment: Professor Mike Bailie tried to prevent Queen's University, Belfast releasing "his" data on tree-rings but he lost the case in 2010. No scientist should ever be against the publishing of experimental data in any case.

Comment: The title is "My master’s thesis’ results will be published without my consent." Why is lack of your consent the issue to highlight? Isn't the problem that they're threatening to publish it without *crediting* you?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The issue seems real enough to me.  I have never been on a research project where there was NOT behind the scenes ownership of gathered data.  Spoken and unspoken agreements on who can publish research based on parts of data collected, questions asked and results analyzed.  I know many in my field who feel rightly or wrongly that they own certain datasets, even those based on public funding.  At least in my field the notion that someone could simply lift *your data* and publish whatever they wanted based on it is absurd.  If they did so without credit, they would be dismissed for plagiarism.

Answer (score 46):

> Part of the results I obtained were published in my master’s thesis, which was submited via an online tool to my university; so there is proof that that work is mine, I guess.

Let me first say a meta comment - once you publish a set of results, they are no longer 'yours'. They belong, in part, to the institution that funded you, to your advisor who helped you write your thesis, and to other coauthors/colleagues who helped you along the way. Research is a *collaborative* act.

To your specific case, I strongly doubt that you have proprietary rights to the data. You got the results as part of a Master's thesis supported by an academic institution that has rights to the data. What's more, once you published your thesis, anything in it can be used in future publications **if it is properly credited** (for example, if the dataset was published as an addendum to your thesis, it's fair to use it). That's basically the essence of academic progress.

Just like any other idea that appears in your thesis, the moment that you decided to publish it (as opposed to, say, patenting it and starting a company to commercialize it), others can cite it and potentially use parts of it in their work (doesn't even have to be the advisor, literally anyone can).

If the data is not published, I still argue that you could possibly be in the wrong in this case as well. From a proprietary perspective, you did not work alone. Your advisor and academic institution supported you, offered you tools (free access to software to develop your tools, access to your advisor, an office, classes you took, perhaps a laptop and computing services etc.). It is unethical (and a bit selfish) on your part to ignore all of the effort put into your thesis by others, and withhold the work from being published.

See a similar discussion [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/91357/100323).

Comment: On the other hand, he may have paid a substantial fee for all that (*supported you, offered you tools (free access to software to develop your tools, access to your advisor, an office, classes you took, perhaps a laptop and computing services etc.)*) In the UK this is £9250 p.a.

Comment: This is true, but his research still belongs (in part) to the university/coauthors. For example, he can't go and patent ideas in his thesis without going through his university.

Comment: More concretely, he most likely signed some kind of waiver/acknowledgement of this when he got into the program

Comment: I agree that the data is not "only" mine. As you say, I didn't work alone. However, I don't think that not crediting me as an author is correct from their part either. On another note, my thesis wasn't published and it's not available to the public.

Comment: Once you submitted your thesis to your institution then it is usually in the public domain. You should most certainly be credited for your work as I mention!

Here's MIT's repository as an example https://libguides.mit.edu/diss

Comment: @Spark Public domain != publicly available. The OP still has full copyright rights to their thesis and they probably granted a license to their university to host their work as a condition for enrolling/graduating. But I doubt that anyone can just copy&paste it and make money out of it legally without the OP permission.

Comment: Depending on the intellectual contribution of OP, without citing the thesis, the other authors may become guilty of plagiarism. They must at the very least cite the thesis.

Comment: Of course, see my remark in bold within the question. Is it not clear from my answer?

Comment: "supported by an academic institution" This appears to be an assumption.  It's entirely possible that _the OP supported the university_ by paying to attend.  If you pay to access/use particular facilities while doing your work (or even if you _don't_ pay and just use them for free with the owner's permission), the owner of those facilities doesn't get to claim (full or part) ownership of your work.  At least not automatically; that would have to be explicitly set out in whatever agreement exists between the person doing the work and the person/organization providing the facilities.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Note that data is usually not copyrightable. Related discussion in [law.se](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11359/can-you-copyright-data).

Comment: In point of fact, some university policies state their copyright policy publicly.  Harvard for example states outright that public access is a huge consideration for their IP policy:

https://otd.harvard.edu/faculty-inventors/resources/policies-and-procedures/statement-of-policy-in-regard-to-intellectual-property/

These policies are written such that if you undertake research at the institution, the policy applies.  It doesn't matter if you are paid or not; pay tuition or not. The value of the intellectual community cannot be calculated.  If you could have done this alone, why didn't you?

Comment: @aroth students pay for the right to go to the university and obtain services from it. This says nothing about owning the products of their work.

Comment: @user71659 A thesis is a text. As all text it is protected by copyright. Copy&pasting partially or in full a copyrighted work is copyright infringment. It may or may not be plagiarism depending on the circumstance. So they cannot copy&paste the thesis in partial or in full and claim as their result. Obviously they could take the data and rewrite everything. I just wanted to clarify the fact that academic texts are not in the public domain. Public domain is a copyright concept. They are often publicly available.

Comment: @Giacomo Alzetta you’re right of course, no one is saying that this case calls for a revocation of authorship!

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Wrong! The fact that it's text does not mean it's all protected by copyright. For example, if a thesis includes the work of Shakespeare, that text is not copyrighted anymore, and I can freely copy and paste that. Likewise, there were court cases of the copyrightablility of telephone directories, which are not: that is non-creative data and uncopyrightable, so I can copy and paste that all I want. Again, just because it's text does not mean it's copyrightable.

Comment: @user71659 Are you claiming that including any citation anywhere in a text makes **the whole text** not under copyright? You are very mistaken. What you are saying is obvious: public quotes and other parts of text obtained via a license from the original copyright holder maintain their status but everything **you** write is under your copyright. A thesis should definitely be mostly written by yourself.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Read the original question carefully! Direct quote: "Now it has come to my attention that **my data has been used** to write a paper that will soon be sent for publishing". It says "data" not "explanatory prose". Data can be text too, for example survey responses. Again, data is generally not copyrightable and the OP has a belief not fitting with actual law.

Answer (score 10):

As I understand it, they are not republishing your *results*. They are publishing new results based on *data you gathered*.

If that's the case, the best you can do to get credit is to make a *data publication* of your own. This is a relatively new idea, but it exists, and it is gaining traction in recent years due to increased political pressure for data reuse. What you do is to find either a journal or a data repository in your area which supports publishing data of the type you gathered. Your data set gets a DOI, and is citable in the same way that other academic artefacts (methods papers, monographs, etc.) are.

If you don't wish to do that, you probably have no other options. Institutions generally see data generated by people working for them as their institutional property, and frequently make sure that this is reflected in e.g. work contracts. Frequently PIs think that the data belongs to them and not to their employer, but I won't go into disputes around that, since you are not the PI, you were in the lowest position of the academic food chain. Your desire to prevent your group's publication is not supported by widely accepted moral/customary rules of how this works, and certainly not by legal ones.

In the end, you can get credit or nothing, but if you try stopping them from publishing, you are likely to get nothing but a reputation for a misinformed querulant. But as this is a highly interesting area where new rules are crystalizing by the day, I can only urge you to be part of the one solution which is, in the long term, in the best interest of society and academia as a whole: do the data publication.

Update: If you don't know how go about making a data publication, the first thing you can do is to see if your institution has a core facility offering the internal service of research data management. If not, ask a librarian. If everything else fails, maybe a new question on SE is in order, "how do I find a journal that takes data publications from my discipline".

Comment: The OP states that the thesis is not public but only available to his advisor and a small set of selected people. This makes it sound like there is an agreement of non-disclosure (or restricted/limited access) for the results of this work between certain parties, e.g. the sponsor of this research work and the university. This agreement might likely include the primary data and would be violated if the OP publishes the data without written consent of the PI or the university.

Comment: @Ghanima The question doesn't make it clear if the thesis is not available because there is an NDA, or because nobody ever bothered to make it public. If there is an NDA, then there is the question, what does it cover? If the advisor can publish a paper based on the data, then maybe the data itself is publishable too, the OP should consult somebody for such details. If the data itself is indeed not publisheable, then the OP could still ask for the advisor to cite the thesis as a proxy for the data citation. Even if it is not available, it is citeable.

Answer (score 2):

To decide how to proceed, there are several aspects to consider here:

1. if they use the data without crediting you, they "stole" the results. They definitely can't do that without repercussions (and they shouldn't have threatened you!); on the other hand:
2. if they use the date and credit you, but you refuse to be an author for personal reasons (i.e. not for reasons that you do not believe in the results or publication), this gives you the power to block the publication.

An author has the right and probably duty to refuse being a coauthor if he does not believe in the integrity or quality of the paper and its results. Is this the case?

Just blocking it (by refusing to be a coauthor) for other than such objective reasons is - as badly as you may have been treated - a disservice to the scientific community, to the values of science and, ultimately, also to yourself.

These are the criteria that I would consider foremost in such a situation.

Disclaimer: I cannot judge the importance of being first author in your field, so I won't comment on that. In my field, it is not that important.

Comment: About first author - sometimes when looking at paper, if the first author has loads of titles, then I assume that the last two authors listed did the real work...

Comment: (2) This is not necessarily true. If the data was published as part of the thesis, it's in public domain, and can be used depending on the specific license that was used.

Comment: If OP refuses to be a co-author the authors could still credit them in an acknowledgement ("User102823 gathered the data.") or a citation ("User102823, *private communication*).

Comment: They didn't "steal" anything.  The results are owned by the institution, not the OP.  The OP can refuse to publish, but he ***cannot*** control what happens to any data or results from the work he did, because that is entirely owned by the institution.  (Which is the same reason he can't take those results and start his own company using them, of course.)  They are also within their rights not to credit him as an author.  They may credit him with gathering experimental data, but this does not necessarily make you an author of a paper.

Comment: @Graham It depends on the intellectual contribution required to gather the data. If it is a substantial amount of work, unless it is purely a technician's job (which I do not think it should be, given that OP gets a Masters degree for it), it should warrant co-authorship. If it is minor (probably not: a year's worth of work), it might be an acknowledgement.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Under normal circumstances, of course he's due co-authorship.  But if he's refused to publish already, he's intentionally removed himself from the system.  If they're decent people then they should still credit him, but he can't very well complain if they don't.  They can't leave that research path blocked by one dog-in-the-manger ex-researcher.

Comment: @Graham, by my reading they didn't refuse to publish. They refused to stay in that group to do PhD. Based on the group's threat to publish without credit if they didn't stay being the last communication received regarding this, it doesn't sound like they were offered the option of being involved in publication without staying in the group. It seems to me that leaving the group should not void their claim to their intellectual contributions while part of the group.

Comment: If they publish OP's authorship worthy intellectual contribution claiming it as their own, that would be academic misconduct i.e. "stealing". What parts of the research should count as authorship worthy differs from scenario to scenario. Was the data collection just following instructions provided by others and the authorship worthy contribution analysis of that data?, or did the data collection itself depend on methodology developed by the OP?

Comment: Even if they do actually refuse to be an author, there are numerous other questions here about how to publish given a reluctant or unavailable contributor, I can't recall ever seeing an answer that said "use their work anyway, it is OK not to give them credit." Not using OP's results doesn't mean that research path is completely blocked. There is always the option of reproducing the results on their own.

Answer (score 2):

From what you say it's not clear whether your master thesis has been published, i.e. whether the data/results you obtained and included in the thesis are available to the general academic public. If that is the case the [answer by Spark](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/122751/41302) applies.

However, I suspect that your thesis is only available to academics at your old university, perhaps only your former supervisor(s). In this case (and if you continue to take academic interest in the field), you should seek to publish the publishable data/results from your master project. The natural way is to do so in collaboration with your former supervisor. If that is not possible (as it appears in your case) you should still publish your thesis data/results yourself. A simple way is to just publish the master thesis directly on arXiv (but check first whether that is legally possibly with the university).

Comment: Many institutions (like mine) require theses to be published. In my case this meant having a copy bound and deposited in the university library. These are "available to the general public" in the sense that anybody can walk into the library and read them there. (I believe it's are also available from an online thesis repository for a fee).

Comment: This type of "publication" is very limited. If there is no free (no fee) searchable online publication, this is useless. Instead you should really publish the thesis on the arXiv.

Comment: When I did my thesis, arXiv existed, but it was still called the LANL archive, and it's usage was very limited (maybe the particle physics community only?). I never even heard of it under the arXiv name until 10 years later.

Comment: @ThePhoton Wikipedia has a [nice entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv#History) on the history of the arXiv.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt whether the OP has much of a claim in this matter.

The OP submitted his thesis to gain a Master's degree.  It has in effect been handed over to the university and to all intents and purposes has become the possession of the university.

On the other hand, the OP, unless he has signed a non-disclosure agreement, would probably be able to make use of the knowledge gained in researching his thesis to publish further material based on that knowledge and thus pre-empt anyone else claiming credit for the OP's work.

There's no point in getting too up-tight about such matters, though. Many of us have had work we've done published by others unaltered and without any attribution or credit.